# Material-UI createShallow to retrieve component for enzyme unit testing fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm trying to implement a simple unit test with Enzyme on Material-UI with a component inside MuiThemeProvider. To test a basic version I took the example from the [manual](https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/) but whenever I run `npm test` I get the error below.

Any advice on how I can retrieve a component from inside a MuiThemeProvider to use later in a dive and finally in a unit test?

```
  Cannot find module 'react' from 'MuiThemeProvider.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './MuiThemeProvider.d.ts'
        './MuiThemeProvider.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js:26:37)
```

My minimal test and component are defined below in file `test/ButtonTest.js`:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'

import { createShallow } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

export function MyComponent() {
    return (<MuiThemeProvider>
      <React.Fragment>
        <RaisedButton
                    label='Next'
                    primary={true}
                />
        </React.Fragment>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
}

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let shallow;

  beforeAll(() => {  
    shallow = createShallow();
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    // TODO: write test
    });
});
```

My setup is defined as below in `test/setupTests.js`,

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

// React 16 Enzyme adapter
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

// Make Enzyme functions available in all test files without importing
global.React = React
global.shallow = shallow
global.render = render
global.mount = mount
```

I found that the problem can be related to babel and therefore configured the `.babelrc` in the project as follows,

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
      "plugins": ["transform-export-extensions"],
      "only": [
        "./**/*.js",
        "node_modules/jest-runtime"
      ]
    }
  },
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

The essential bits from my package.json are,

```
"dependencies": {
    "enzyme": "~3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "~1.14.0",
    "material-ui": "~0.20.2",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "~3.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "~3.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0",
    "react-validation-framework": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "~1.7.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.0"
  }
```